# Startup loading dialog Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, loading, startup

I've got an Android app that uses a WebView. At the startup of the app it checks if the WebView can connect to the server or not. If it can connect there's no problem, the app loads instantly and the WebView is showing the page. But if the server is not available or the connection doesn't work, it takes a few seconds (5-10) before the error message shows. That's because when you have a slow connection, it doesn't show the error message continiously.

So with no connection you see a black screen for about 5-10 seconds. What I want is just a simple loading dialog at the startup of the app. So that you don't see the black screen and people know the app is doing something. How can I archieve this with the most simple but effective way??

Thank you!!

**EDIT:**

Okay this is what I now have, I think it's working but is this the right way? And is it possible to use this Async thread also in the shouldOverideUrlLoading? How can I do that?

```
public class WebviewActivity extends MainActivity {

    private WebView myWebView;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final ScrollView mainScrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01);

        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(WebviewActivity.this, "", "Loading...", true);

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                progressDialog.show();

                if ( isOnline() == false || isOnlineHost() == false )
                    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/errorpage.html");
                else
                    view.loadUrl(url);

                return true;                
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                mainScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
            }
        });

        myWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        myWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                            v.requestFocus();
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){        
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();    
        new checkConnection().execute();
    }

    //DOING THE CONNECTION CHECK IN ANOTHER THREAD  
    public class checkConnection extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{        

        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;              

        protected void onPreExecute(){
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(WebviewActivity.this, "", "Loading...", true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            if ( isOnline() == true && isOnlineHost() == true )
                myWebView.loadUrl(webLink);
            else
                myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/errorpage.html");

            progressDialog.dismiss();           
            return null;
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `AsyncTask` to check for the connectivity in the background while the `ProgressDialog` is shown. Dismiss the dialog after the check is complete.

Comment: That's some new stuff to me, looks hard to do. Could you maybe give me an example or someone else who has some spare time? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html). Do your `isOnlineHost` check in the `doInBackground` method and dismiss the `ProgressDialog` in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: I got something now, and it's working the right way I think. Can you please check my source? And is it possible to use the same AsyncTask for the part in the shouldOverideUrlLoading? Can you tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your class implements `Runnable`. Then use something like:

```
private WebView myWebView;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
```

As global variables,

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Title", "Loading...", true, false);

Thread thread = new Thread(this);
thread.start();
```

To START the thread,

```
public void run() {
            // Time consuming task
    }
```

As what's run in the thread, and

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    // What to do when thread is finished
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
    };
```

To handle the completion of the thread.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But man, I really don't understand this stuff. Maybe it's to much to ask but can you give me an example using my code? Thank you very much!

Comment: If you can give me an isolated section of the time-consuming code, what to do on completion, and tell me where to start the thread (I can't draw that out of your code), I can.

Comment: I got it already by myself, that's the best way to learn it right ;)